# Toolbar disappears when viewing PDF HTML5 WebView2

Tags: wpf, pdf, webview2

I am using a WebView2 control in a WPF application to show a PDF to the user

This is normally displayed with a nice little toolbar, all part and parcel of rendering a PDF in a WebView2 control, allowing the user to navigate to other pages, zoom in or out, rotate, etc.

[image]

However, we found that as the window gets a bit narrower at some point this toolbar simply disappears. Is there something we can do to stop this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the available space for the PDF toolbar shrinks the PDF toolbar shows fewer and fewer controls. This is also true in the browser. However, in the browser the minimum horizontal width of the browser window is a value at which the PDF toolbar is still visible.

I'm not sure if this behavior is by design or not. You can try opening a bug report about this on the [WebView2 feedback repo](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/new/choose).

Comment: Thanks David

Done.

https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/1685